# SQL Rejecting batch insert because single row is duplicate

Tags: php, mysql, insert, duplicates, composite-key

I don't know the proper term, but by "Batch insert" what I mean is..

```
INSERT INTO `table` (`column1`, `column2`, `column3`) VALUES 
("value1", "value2", "value3"),
("value4", "value5", "value6"),
("value7", "value8", "value9")
```

We're inserting multiple rows in a single query to save resources.

We have a composite key set up on this table to avoid getting duplicate records. Problem is, when there is a duplicate record, it rejects the entire "batch", so in the example above, if "value1" already existed in the `column1` column, it will not insert any of the 3 rows.

We are using PHP with the mysql_ functions (yes, I know they're being deprecated, let's address one problem at a time please)

So my question is, is there a way to insert multiple rows at once where, in the event of a duplicate row, it will still insert the rest of the rows in the "batch"?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the `ignore` keyword

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO `table` ...
```

> If you use the IGNORE keyword, errors that occur while executing the INSERT statement are ignored. For example, **without IGNORE, a row that duplicates an existing UNIQUE index or PRIMARY KEY value in the table causes a duplicate-key error and the statement is aborted. With IGNORE, the row still is not inserted, but no error occurs.** Ignored errors may generate warnings instead, although duplicate-key errors do not.

Answer (score 2):

complementing juerguen's answer, you could also use:

```
INSERT INTO thetable (pageid, name)
VALUES (1, "foo"), (1, "foo")
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE (pagecount = pagecount + 1)
```

that way, you could identify the duplicated row and delete it when the process is finished.

For example, adding a flag field to the table named `is_duplicated`

```
INSERT INTO thetable (pageid, name)
VALUES (1, "foo"), (1, "foo")
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE (is_duplicated = 1)
```

And later:

```
DELETE FROM thetable WHERE is_duplicated = 1
```

Also you could use:

```
SET foreign_key_checks = 0;
```

execute the batch, and then:

```
SET foreign_key_checks = 1;
```

That way, if there is a foreign key that may not exist at that time but it will be created later, the inserts will also keep going.